# Can I use HTML to create a vote button on an email that sends a reply?

Tags: html-email

Situation:

I am a HTML newbie who gets by through Google-fu and I am in charge of a tool which sends HTML email to customers.

I have been asked by our customers (Because pressing reply and typing a single word is really difficult) if I can create buttons on the emails I send which allows them a 1-click reply.

Conditions:

1. The reply has to come from their own email address
2. It needs to go back to the email address that sent the email (We have one template email which can be sent from several addresses)
3. It needs to maintain the same subject line (It contains a reference number to ensure the email is processed correctly when received)
4. Must be created using inline HTML(4 or 5) only (Restrictions of the system that generates the email)
5. Ideally will send the reply immediately (And show them as much in some manner), but opening up a new email already pre-populated is an acceptable alternative

I have struggled to find much at all on this, which leads me to think that it is not possible.

Comment: You mean you want them to be able to reply from their email (google mail) by clicking reply and for you to correctly receive the whole reply message? But everything is done from their own email inbox?

Eather way, everything that goes to and from google mail, has to be pure HTML, I dont think they allow any JS or etc. Unless you would make a button for them to get reddirected, sure, it is possible to put paremeters to URL and then read on inpact with php. But with HTML, I do not think its possible.

Sending and reading data would still need to be PHP end, to generate needed parameters.

Comment: @CommunityIsridiculous Not by clicking the normal reply button, but by clicking a link or button embedded into the body of the email itself. So the email itself would say something like "Hi CommunityIsridiculous, click here to approve, or click here to deny".

Comment: Is some PHP fine, or do you want it to be plain HTML for the server side part. not the mail part

Comment: It has to be entirely HTML. I have limited control over what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using tiny bit of pure javascript, that does not need any external library on your website.

This code goes to your website where you want your check to be made.

```
<script>
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    if(getURLParameter('answ') == 0) document.getElementById('answered_yes').remove();
    else if(getURLParameter('answ') == 1) document.getElementById('answered_no').remove();
    else {
        document.getElementById('answered_yes').remove();  document.getElementById('answered_no').remove();
    }
});
</script>

<div id="answered_yes">
THIS IS HOLDER FOR YES ANSWERER //Put your wanted info hare if he answered yes
</div>

<div id="answered_no">
THIS IS HOLDER FOR NO ANSWERER //Put your wanted info hare if he answered no
</div>
```

Now on email links put these type of links.

`<a href="yourwebsite.com/index.php?answ=0" target="_blank" >ANSWER NO</a>`

`<a href="yourwebsite.com/index.php?answ=1" target="_blank" >ANSWER YES</a>`

What this does is simply puts a parameter on a link called answ that has 0 or 1 by my setting and once your website gets a request ***it checks which parameter is it 0 or 1. If its 0 that means we remove the div that says yes, otherwise do the same with no div.***

with only html it is not possible unless you would give him different links as in.

`<a href="yoursite.com/he_answered_no.html" >No</a>`
`<a href="yoursite.com/he_answered_yes.html" >Yes</a>`

And put your contents inside there.

However if you are going to use this script in your website, put that code somewhere in the body, its not perfect, but it will do the job. Then put your information on yes div and on no div, its going to remove whatever div he answers too.

But like I mentioned, **with purely HTML it is not possible only adding some bits with other languages**, pure javascript should work on any HTML site, unless you are trying to add the code to some kind of platform that blocks any ongoing scripts.

Comment: It isn't actually a website, but an application that sends emails. All I have control of is the HTML body of the email, but thank you. Shame it isn't possible, but that is what I expected anyway.

Comment: Ah I get it. There is few ways to go around it, like sending specific responses to the application itself, however that would again require more access from application than HTML. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a "mailto:" link similar to this:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?subject=Big%20News&body=Body-goes-here">Email Us</a>
```

Here's the link with more info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/

It will open up a prepopulated email with the "to" address, subject line, and body text already inserted. People will be able to modify the text if they want or just click send. You would need to some way to dynamically change the subject line to the one the customer received, but your email tool probably has that capability.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but that still doesn't change the fact that user needs to click multiple buttons, your answer is as same as customer would click reply button himself (He still needs to click send). The question is, can he make it so it would be one click reply like a vote poll. (You open email, get buttons, click one, done). And no mail api would allow sending email without confirmations, it would be easy spam bypass for robots..

Comment: True, it's not the best case scenario, but it is the simplest HTML-only solution that meets the criteria: "opening up a new email already pre-populated is an acceptable alternative"

Comment: Not necessarily my friend. Mailto works by using your default mail program, so imagine a lot of people are using outlooks and etcetera. So now you get a mail that you opened via gmail and you click the button, and suddenly it loads outlook for no reason or similar. While like I said the idea isn't bad, it has way to many factors to go trough via unknown, what if, what if, this approach is not guaranteed to work for every client and *every browser*. And you have so little control over it.